# How to calculate covariance between stocks with different observation periods?

Tags: covariance, excel

Let's say I have three stocks.
Stock A and B I have daily prices from 1 Jan 2000 to 31 Dec 2018.
Stock C I only have daily prices from 1 Jan 2005 to 31 Dec 2018.

Is it possible to calculate the covariance matrix of these stocks, using Excel, using the full data set of each stock without discarding Stock A and B's 2000-2004 daily price data?

Comment: Short answer: You can calculate $cov(A,B)$ for the full time, but $cov(A,C)$ and $cov(B,C)$ would only be defined since 1 Jan 2005. You could calculated a lagged cross covariance between $xcov(A_{t-T},C_t)$ for $T<5$ years, if that is of interest.

Comment: Thanks very much! Does it make sense if I still use the covariance for A, B and C to optimise the stock allocation using efficient frontier theory (i.e. solve allocation of A B C for given mean, with the goal of minimising standard deviation). Or do I need to make any adjustments?